# React native app BUILD FAILED after installing @react-native-firebase/messaging

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add notifications to my app. I installed @react-native-firebase/app: "^8.4.7" and everything went smoothly, but when I try to install @react-native-firebase/messaging: "^7.9.2" and run (npx react-native run-android) I am always getting BUILD FAILED.

```
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\user\Desktop\sato\node_modules\@react- 
native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 25.12.0
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 18.1.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\user\Desktop\sato\node_modules\@react- 
native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 8.4.7 (8,4,7 - 8004007)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 16
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\user\Desktop\sato\node_modules\react- 
native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_messaging
:react-native-firebase_messaging package.json found at 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sato\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\user\Desktop\sato\node_modules\@react- 
native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_messaging:firebase.bom using default value: 25.12.0
:react-native-firebase_messaging package.json found at 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sato\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\package.json
:react-native-firebase_messaging:version set from package.json: 7.9.2 (7,9,2 - 7009002)
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.minSdk using custom value: 16
:react-native-firebase_messaging:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\user\Desktop\sato\node_modules\react- 
native\android

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: try to build in android studio and check what error u got in logcat

Comment: Thanks man I fount the problem and this link helped me [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#java)